# Can't send data to database when update data flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a new Flutter user, here I want to explain my problem, I have a problem when I want to update data, the data can't be entered into the database, there is an error when I send data to the database.
[image]

Is there something wrong with my logic code on flutter ? Here's my source snippet

**API.DART**

```
updateData(apiURL, id, body ) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiURL + '/' + id.toString();
    await _getToken();
    return await http.put(
      fullUrl,
      headers: _setHeaders(),
      body: json.encode(body),
    );
  }
```

**Nasabah_service.dart**

```
  static Future<List<Nasabah>> updateUser(id) async {
    Map<String, String> data;
    final response = await Network().updateData(baseUrl, id, data,);
    List<Nasabah> list = parseResponse(response.body);
    return list;
  }
```

Here's the update function on the formfield

```
void _update() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    var data = {
      "nama_debitur" : _nama_debiturController.text,
      "alamat" : _alamatController.text,
      "no_telp" : _no_telpController.text,
      "no_ktp" : _no_ktpController.text,
      "no_selular" : _no_selularController.text
    };
    print(data);

    var res = await Network().updateData(NasabahService.baseUrl, 'mstdebitur' , data);
    var body = json.decode(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      localStorage.setString('mstdebitur', json.encode(body['mstdebitur']));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Berhasil Disimpan'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      ));

    } else {
      // if (body['message']['nama_debitur'] != null) {
      //   _showMsg(body['message']['nama_debitur'][0].toString());
      // } else if (body['message']['alamat'] != null) {
      //   _showMsg(body['message']['alamat'][0].toString());
      // } else if (body['message']['no_telp'] != null) {
      //   _showMsg(body['message']['no_telp'][0].toString());
      // }
      // else if (body['message']['no_ktp'] != null) {
      //   _showMsg(body['message']['no_ktp'][0].toString());
      // }
      // else if (body['message']['no_selular'] != null) {
      //   _showMsg(body['message']['no_selular'][0].toString());
      // }
      // ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      //     .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: Text("Gagal")));
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your API using postman?

Comment: yes i have checked, if you use postman all CRUD is already running @MiftakhulArzak

Comment: The error indicates that there is an invalid input for integer. Maybe you added `no_ktp` as `String` but the database you want is integer.